# C : converting binary to decimal

Tags: c

Is there any dedicated function for converting the binary values to decimal values. 
such as  (1111 to 15 ) , ( 0011 to 3 ) .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you getting these binary numbers? like `int i = 10011; // not really binary` or a string?

Comment: yea ,it will be string only...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) function has a `base` parameter you can use for this purpose.

Here's an example with some basic error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char* input = "11001";
    char* endptr;

    int val = strtol(input, &endptr, 2);

    if (*endptr == '\0')
    {
        printf("Got only the integer: %d\n", val);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Got an integer %d\n", val);
        printf("Leftover: %s\n", endptr);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

This correctly parses and prints the integer 25 (which is `11001` in binary). The error handling of `strtol` allows noticing when parts of the string can't be parsed as an integer in the desired base. You'd want to learn more about this by reading in the reference I've linked to above.

Answer (score 1):

Parse it with [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/), then convert to a string with one of the [printf](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fprintf.html) functions.  E.g.

```
char binary[] = "111";
long l = strtol(binary, 0, 2);
char *s = malloc(sizeof binary);
sprintf(s, "%ld\n", l);
```

This allocates more space than needed.