# How to convert from a binary string to binary unsigned char

Tags: c

**First problem:** I have a binary string "11001" I convert it to an int with this function which converts it to 25, and when I return it, it returns '25 x19' instead of unsigned char 11001.

**Second problem:** when I enter binary string "1111", the masking works until it reach the masking "1000" which doesn't work, but "10000" - the last iteration of the masking suddenly does work. meaning:
0001 + 0010 + 0100 + 10000 = 23

instead of 0001 + 0010 + 0100 + 1000 = 15.

any ideas?

**I'll explain what I want to do:**

1. I get an input from a .txt file which is "11001", I must convert it to UNSIGNED CHAR, which is 'just' 11001.

What I want to do is to convert "11001" to 25, and 25 to 11001, and then cast it to 11001 unsigned char.

```
unsigned char stringToBinary(char tmpSubjectStatus[])
{
    int tmpInteger;
    int tmpBinary = 0; //convert tmpInteger into binary number
    unsigned char tmpBinaryCh;
    int i = 0;
    int mostRightbit = 16;
    tmpInteger = atoi(tmpSubjectStatus); //Convert from string to int
    while (i < 5){
        if (((16 >> i) & tmpInteger) != 0){
            tmpBinary += (16 >> i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    tmpBinaryCh = (unsigned char)tmpBinary;
    return tmpBinaryCh;
}
```

Here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/QNNf3zs7

Comment: why reinvent wheel? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482211/c-converting-binary-to-decimal

Comment: It is absolutely unclear to me what you want to do. I see many strange things, e.g. converting a string repesenting a binary number to int and returning an integer cast to a char.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie What I want to do is to convert "11001" to 25, and 25 to 11001, and then cast it to 11001 unsigned char

Comment: @Dummy00001 Because if we re-invent the wheel, we can make it square shaped! It will be slower, it will be bumpy, it will possibly cause the vehicle to crash.

Comment: Suggest instead `unsigned char stringToBinary(char tmpSubjectStatus[]) { return strtoul(tmpSubjectStatus, 0, 2); } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are doing, but to convert a string of ones and zeroes to an integer, the following should work:

```
unsigned char stringToBinary(char tmpSubjectStatus[])
{
    int tmpInteger = 0;
    while (*tmpSubjectStatus)
    {
        tmpInteger <<= 1;
        if (*tmpSubjectStatus == '1')
            tmpInteger += 1;
        tmpSubjectStatus++;
    }
    return (unsigned char) tmpInteger;
}
```

EDIT: replaced code with corect version (minor bug).

Description: As soon as a new digit is seen, the (binary) digits are shifted 1 place to the left and the new digit is added (a 1 or a 0). The first time it is redundant but shifting integer value zero 1 place to the left has no effect.

Comment: from a string the first character (most left when you look at your screen should be the MSB). So doing <<=1 is taking the string the wrong way. I'm not sure you can do it your way without the size of the string.

Comment: mine: http://pastebin.com/WhWJfTxg

Comment: Curious that code is doing a mix of "bit-wise, arithmetic" with "shift, add", rather than a "shift, or" or "multiply,add".

Comment: @chux, whatever. `+= 1` could have been `|= 1` and `<<= 1` could have been `*= 2`. They are equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

1000 = 2³ = 8 and not 16. So the `mostRightbit`variable you set should be 8 to me.

Comment: mostRightBit isn't used in the function. and when i = 1, 16 >> i is 8, so it should return 1 and not zero.

Comment: but i is initialized to 0 and you use 16 directly so it's the same issue as 16 >> 0 = 16 so you are already greater than 15 the maximum for a 4-bit binary word

Comment: yes but why 16 >> 0 = 16 & 0111 is 16? why 10000 & 01111 is 16?